# Dice Game - need to roll more dice based upon circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a game idea. Weapons can be equipped on your character. Different weapons have different amounts of damage dice and critical hit dice. I have it working currently so that the program rolls the appropriate amount of dice based on your equipped weapon.

However, the program only rolls one critical dice, despite whether the equipped weapon contains two critical roll dies.

```
var WepEquipped = { "name": "Broken Sword", "attack_dice": "2", "critical_dice": "1", "min_base_dmg": "2", "max_base_dmg": "12", "max_total_dmg": "24", "weapon_type": "Slash" };

function Attack(rolls) {
var total = 0;
var dice = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= rolls; i++) {
    var d6 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    $("#dice_container").append("<div class='die_roll'><p class='atk-roll'>" + d6 + "</p></div>");
    dice.push(d6);
    total += d6;
}

// Needs to be able to roll for multiple critical dice
if ($.grep(dice, function (elem) {
    return elem === dice[0];
    }).length == rolls) {
        var d12 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
        total += d12;
        $("#dice_container").append("<div class='die_roll'><p id='crit-roll'>" + d12 + "</p></div>");
    }
    $("#attack").html("<div>You attack for " + total + "</div>");
};

$('#attack_button').off('click').on('click', function(){
    $('.die_roll').hide();
    Attack(WepEquipped.attack_dice);
    // Attack(WepEquipped.attack_dice);
});
```

I can explain much more, but I hope this is enough code to grasp what I'm asking. Something here needs to change but I cannot figure out what:

```
// Needs to be able to roll for multiple critical dice
if ($.grep(dice, function (elem) {
return elem === dice[0];
}).length == rolls) {
    var d12 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    total += d12;
    $("#dice_container").append("<div class='die_roll'><p id='crit-roll'>" + d12 + "</p></div>");
}
$("#attack").html("<div>You attack for " + total + "</div>");
};
```

Comment: You don't need to loop over the number of rolls, a single expression can return a valid value for *n* dices. (It doesn't answer your question though.)

Comment: I feel like you should be doing this in anothe way. I think that the grep part is problematic; I'm not sure about the usage you do of this. Why are you comparing with the first die only in this?

Comment: @YannChabot To be honest, I'm not sure. This is my first time using Javascript in such detail. I've had some help to get this far and it's working...I haven't had any reason to change it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your grep returns the number of elements in the dice array that equal to your first roll and if the length of that array equals the number of rolls that were made you roll the critical dice once.

```
if ($.grep(dice, function (elem) {
    return elem === dice[0];
    }).length == rolls) {
        var d12 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
        total += d12;
        $("#dice_container").append("<div class='die_roll'><p id='crit-roll'>" + d12 + "</p></div>");
    }
    $("#attack").html("<div>You attack for " + total + "</div>");
};
```

If you're trying to roll as many times as the grep returns you need something like this.

```
var crits = $.grep(dice, function (elem) {return elem === dice[0];});
if( crits.length  == rolls ){
  for( var x=0;x<crits.length;x++){
     var d12 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
     total += d12;
     $("#dice_container").append("<div class='die_roll'><p id='crit-roll'>" + d12 + "</p></div>");
  }
}
```

Sorry for the double post, was on an abandoned account.

Comment: My thought was I'd have to store the amount of crit dice in a variable somewhere. I'm trying to roll as many crit dice as the "weapon" allows. This number will be between 1-3 crit dice, so I'm not sure it matters how many numbers are in the grep, it was just the way I had come up with to check if the original roll had all matching dice.

Comment: Then pass the number of crit dice needed to be rolled alongside of the dice to be rolled. 

Attack(WepEquipped.attack_dice, WebEquipped.critical_dice);


function Attack(rolls, critRolls) {

then loop that many times instead of crits.length or add another loop inside the loop i provided using the critRolls as the counter upper boundry.

Comment: Wow, that certainly does the trick. Thank you for showing me this!